# How to enable ISR for static routing with fallback in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I know that enabling ISR with fallback needs to export `getStaticPaths` in the page:

```js
export const getStaticPaths = () => {
  return {
    paths: []
  , fallback: 'blocking'
  }
}
```

However, `getStaticPaths` is only work for dynamic routing, such as `[slug].jsx`.

I want to enable ISR for static routing with fallback like `index.jsx`, is it impossible?

Additional information: I cannot pre-generate the page at build-time.

Answer (score 0):

The [`fallback` key](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required) is used in `getStaticPaths` to control how new paths, not generated at build-time, are handled for dynamic routes. It can either return a `404` page (`fallback: false`), or allow Next.js to generate new pages (`fallback: blocking` or `fallback: true`).

Given that your `index.jsx` is not a dynamic route this doesn't apply, and there's no need for a fallback since that page will always be pre-generated at build-time.

---

On the other hand, [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) allows you to regenerate existing pages. It's enabled through the `revalidate` property in `getStaticProps`, and can be used in both dynamic and non-dynamic routes.

```js
// index.jsx

export async function getStaticProps() {

    return {
        props: {
            //...
        }
        revalidate: 10 // Enables page regeneration
    }
}
```

When a request is made to `index.jsx`, it will initially show the cached, pre-generated page.

From the docs:

> - Any requests to the page after the initial request and before 10    seconds are also cached and instantaneous.
> - After the 10-second window, the next request will still show the cached (stale) page.
> - Next.js triggers a regeneration of the page in the background.
> - Once the page has been successfully generated, Next.js will invalidate the    cache and show the updated product page. If the
>   background    regeneration fails, the old page will stay unaltered.

Comment: What if I cannot pre-generate the page at build-time?

Comment: ISR only works for statically generated pages, i.e. pages that use `getStaticProps`. Is this not the case for your `index.js` page?

Comment: I do use `getStaticProps`, but I need to build a reusable Docker image. The configuration required for pages does not exist at build-time.

Comment: If the configuration is not available at build-time couldn't you look into [server-side rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) instead?

Comment: AFAIK, Next.js does not provide stale-while-revalidate for SSR.

Comment: You can use the `Cache-Control` header for that with `getServerSideProps`, see [Next.js Caching](https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#caching).

Comment: No, it is HTTP caching, not SSR caching. It requires an [SPR](https://vercel.com/blog/serverless-pre-rendering) service provider like Vercel to work.